# Advantages of claiming a keep or a resource to guild

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

Is there any real advantage or bonus granted to your guild if someone claims a resource (farm, mine or lumbermill) or a keep in Cyrodiil?

I looked into the documentation, and on many sites, and didn't find any reference to actual bonuses or status for your guild, apart from seeing the name and location of the owned resource on the guild tab.